# OPENSSL_malloc C implementation questions

Tags: c

I was looking at BoringSSL OPENSSL_malloc implementation and I saw a really weird code right here:

[image: Code snippet]

OPENSSL_MALLOC_PREFIX I see is defined to be 8, so why did they put the condition if (size + OPENSSL_MALLOC_PREFIX < size), since it can never tecnically be true?

Also what does he mean by "the tag being discarded by the linker" or "optimising away the reference at the time of writing" in the comment?

Here's where I've taken the source code from:
https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/crypto/mem.c#L132

Comment: The way I read it, this is to have a reference to the symbol `kBoringSSLBinaryTag` somewhere in the code so that it gets linked in. As you say, the `if` condition can never be true, so the code path is never entered. Apparently, they want the tag to always be present in any binary that uses this code.

Comment: Please, [don't post the code messages as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError what if `size` is large enough for addition to cause unsigned integer wrap-around? Unlikely but in theory it should be possible.

Comment: Then `goto err` will happen, whatever that then means.

Answer (score 1):

> OPENSSL_MALLOC_PREFIX I see is defined to be 8, so why did they put the condition if (size + OPENSSL_MALLOC_PREFIX < size), since it can never tecnically be true?

It actually can be true. Assume `size_t` is a typedef of uint64_t; it is reasonable to do as `sizeof(uint64_t)==8`. If the number of bytes requested for allocation (`size` variable )is larger than `UINT64_MAX - 8` then this variable will wrap around, as if size_t were stored in complement-2 format. This is perfectly well defined by the language standard. Note where the number of allocated bytes is stored.

As for `kBoringSSLBinaryTag`: notice it's a static variable, i.e. it is local to the translation unit. Compiler is free to optimize that away, inline it, as long as it satisfies the as-if rule.
However, taking it's address as it were volatile and dereferencing it, forces the compiler to treat the readout as if it were a side effect, or in other words: it forces the compiler to assume the variable might have changed by means other than regular control flow, effectively preventing the variable from being optimized away.

Note that the comment states quite explicitly what those bytes are for:

```c
// kBoringSSLBinaryTag is a distinctive byte sequence to identify binaries that
// are linking in BoringSSL and, roughly, what version they are using.
static const uint8_t kBoringSSLBinaryTag[18] = {
```

Long story short, this is a way of forcing the compiler and linker to embed that array somewhere inside the binary, without needing to define a publicly accessible symbol, i.e. without cluttering the API with it.